# visual studio 2010 issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I write a program using C++ and I want to run it, I can't catch the console window. I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> and it does not work.

I want the window to stay open and wait, even it finishes executing. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Wanna" is not an English word, proper pronouns like "I" should be capitalised and bizarre punctuation like misplaced ellipses and multiple question marks should be actively discouraged (it doesn't become any _more_ of a question just by ending it with "?????" rather than "?"). Does no-one take pride in their writing skills nowadays? Oh, yeah, and get off my lawn :-)

Comment: i don't want cin or cin.get()
i want some way to finish executing to the end

what's wrong with Visual Studio 2010!!!

Comment: @Ruba: Nothing is wrong. It's a console application, run it from a console.

Comment: Which edition of MS Visual Studio 2010 are you using? Also, which Windows OS are you using?

Comment: @paxdiablo: From someone who might not be a native english speaker, "wanna" or non-capitalized "i" don't bother me. But there's never an excuse for "?????" :)

Answer (score 2):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540969/missing-press-any-key-to-continue-when-lauching-with-ctrl-f5

In the older versions it would default to the console subsystem even if you selected "empty project", but not in 2010, so you have to set it manually. To do this select the project in the solution explorer on the right or left (probably is already selected so you don't have to worry about this). Then select "project" from the menu bar drop down menus, then select "*project_name* properties" > "configuration properties" > "linker" > "system" and set the first property, the drop down "subsystem" property to "console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)". The console window should now stay open after execution as usual.

Comment: not sure why nobody up-voted this, this is the correct answer for the problem described (just used the solution myself), although some might just find doing the cin.get() solution may be faster

Answer (score 1):

try using `system("Pause");` as the last line on your code (before the return of your main function)

Comment: i tried it ... but i don't want to "pause" it ... i wanna the program to finish executing ...because when i want see destructor for some class it won't work until it finish at all ... got me??

Comment: Encapsulate your program in a method, call that method from main(), and add cin.get() after the method returns. This is a windows 'feature'

Comment: i'll try it.. thanks:)
But i didn't understand why there is this issue with vs2010?? it wasn't in vs2008

Comment: Ctrl+F5 works for me (I'm using VS2010), it says "Press any key to continue ...", can you show us your source code ?

Comment: @Ruba: It looks like you want to put a breakpoint at the destructor of a global object. Is that correct? Instead of Ctrl+F5, do simple F5

Comment: I am not sure if it will change anything but try system("pause"); without the capital P.

Comment: Case shouldn't matter but, based on comments, I don't think that's what OP wants. There may be something being output by the destructors of objects created in main (or static objects). Pausing before exiting main will not show that output.

Comment: @Ars : i'm studying c++ in my college ... so i'm trying alot of codes ..not specific program ...

Comment: Can you try to debug step by step at the end of your program, and check if there's any exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F5 should work. Just in case, if you have the source of your program, add the following just before the closing brace of main.

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

the program will wait for you to enter some value.

If you want a breakpoint to be triggerred in debugger, do simple F5 instead of Ctrl+F5, after putting a breakpoint on the relevant source line (assuming the source/debug symbols are available)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, Ruba, but it looks like Microsoft removed this nifty little feature when moving from VS2008 to VS2010.

I can't find anything on MSDN, the web in general, or VS options to turn it back on.

My advice is to bypass the environment altogether for testing your application. Simply open a `cmd.exe` window in your runtime directory (debug or release or whatever), build the executable within the IDE then switch to the command window and enter `testprog.exe` to run your program.

Make sure you include any required command line parameters and, after you've entered it the first time, you can just use the up-arrow to retrieve the last command.

Yes, it's a bit of a pain but, until someone comes up with a better solution, it's probably the best way to ensure you see all the output while ensuring the program has shut down completely.

Comment: Why would Microsoft do something like? :S

Comment: I decline to comment on that one, @Alerty :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a breakpoint at `main()`'s closing curly brace if you want to see the console after the program is finished.

Comment: adding breakpoint didn't work with me .


the best solution for now i think is to put my whole code in some function and call it in the main .. the i put cin>>i for example in the main at the end

Answer (score 0):

You should create VS 2010 C++ Projects as below:

New project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32ConsoleApplication

In this way you will be getting "Press any key to continue..." when you run program with `ctrl+F5`, as it was in VS 2008.

**EDIT :**

New project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32ConsoleApplication -> Next -> Check 'Empty project' -> Finish = what you actually need.